# How to set window title in the GNU screen to a hostname of current machine?

Tags: gnu-screen

There is a documentation about setting window title: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Naming-Windows.html

I don't want to change .bashrc on all machines to make dynamic screen. However it will be good set hotkey in my .screenrc to set title using :title (C-a A) command with proper argument.

Maybe there is a solution to provide an output from `uname -n` to :titile command. Or something similar which automatically or semi-automatically sets window title to hostname.

Questions are:

- is there a way to provide output of `uname -n` to :title command?
- is there any other way to set window title to current hostname without changing .bashrc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to solve it:

1. Print out sequence which gnu screen can parse for window titile `ESC k my-titile ESC \`. Screen will extract `my-title`. It can be done via:

```
printf '\ek%s\e\\' $(uname -n);
```

2. Run `screen -X title my-titile` to set a titile of current window.

Since I want to do it for all hosts which I sshed into, there is a trick to wrap actual ssh command into ssh() function using one of aforementioned approaches.

E.g.:

```
ssh() { printf '\ek%s\e\\' "$1"; command ssh "$@"; }
```

Thanks to #screen on freenode : )

ref.: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Titles.html#Dynamic-Titles